# Fill empty pandas column based on condition on others columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following toy dataframe:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
# print dataframe. 
df
```

and I create an empty column which I want to fill later:

```
df['foo'] = df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)
```

I want to fill the empty column based on conditions on the other two columns. For example:

```
 if (df['Name']=='tom' and df['Age']==10):
     df['foo'] = 'x1'
```

I got the following error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: df['foo'] =np.where((df['Name']=='tom')&(df['Age']==10),'x1','')

Comment: this question is over voted

Answer (score 3):

Dataframe needs to be indexed and accessed differently:

```
df['foo'] = ''
df.loc[(df['Name'] == 'tom') & (df['Age'] == 10), 'foo'] = 'x1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['foo'] = np.where((df['Name'] == 'tom') & (df['Age'] == 10), 'x1', '')
```

Using np.where functionality is simpler in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According to error ,here you are comparing whole series df['Name'] with 'tom' and same with other condition. you have to write this condition for every value  pandas series.
For that you can use apply function.

```
def new_column(df1):
    if (df1['Name']=='tom' and df1['Age']==10):
        df1['foo'] = 'x1'

df.apply(new_column)
```